# ¿Cómo usar una variable PHP dentro de una consulta SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola soy nuevo en SQL y estoy desarrollando un proyecto utilizando PHP y MySQL en el que un usuario se loguea y puede descargar archivos que son para el. ¿Cómo puedo incluir una variable para obtener información seleccionada de la tabla?
Esta parte si me devuelve el nombre del usuario

```php
<h1>Bienvenido <?php echo $user['usuario']; ?></h1>
```

Este es el código que tengo:

```html
<body>
  <h1>Bienvenido <?php echo $user['usuario']; ?></h1>

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="90%" align="center">Archivos</th>
                    <th align="center">Acción</th>  
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <?php
            $query=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE user_id={$user['usuario']}");
            while($row=$query->fetch()){
                $name=$row['name'];
            ?>
            <tr>
            
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<?php echo $name ;?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <center><button class="alert-success"><a href="download.php?filename=<?php echo $name;?>&f=<?php echo $row['fname'] ?>"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></a></button></center>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviamente en la consulta `where` la variable `$user['usuario']` no funciona, pero en el `echo` si obtengo ese valor, solo necesito que reconozca la información almacenada en el campo usuario de la base de datos para que funcione. ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: que yo sepa, esa consulta no debería de llevar las llaves `{}`

Comment: query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE user_id=$user['usuario']");

Comment: De esa manera me genera el siguiente error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\login-master\views\usuario.view.php on line 47

Comment: Las llaves que pones son correctas. ;)

Comment: Es lo que yo tenía entendido, pero entonces porque me da este error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\login-master\views\usuario.view.php:48 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\login-master\usuario.php(18): require() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\login-master\views\usuario.view.php on line 48

Comment: De hecho si en el WHERE user_id pongo un valor de un usuario por ejemplo 'Carlos Martinez' si funciona, pero al tratar de hacerlo con la variable falla

Comment: Mmmm y si pruebas asi: `$query=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE user_id='{$user['usuario']}'");` ya que según veo creo que es porque no lo estas comparando como cadena al igual que lo haces a manito `'Carlos Martinez'`. ;)

Comment: Eso era, muchísimas gracias Israel-ICM, de verdad!

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo que creo es que la variable **$user['usuario'];** no esta definida, ya que se cerro el **?>**, te recomiendo usar session_start() para usar variables de sesión.

```php
session_start();
//Definimos la variable de sesion para el usuario 
$_SESSION['login']=$user['usuario'];
```

Luego ya podemos usar las variables en cualquier pagina, previamente haciendo un **session_start();**

```php
$query=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['login'].");
```

Y por ultimo debes chequear que la columna **name** exista en tu DataBase.

Comment: @Israel-ICM Ok.